# Double posting of comments (Not intended)

Tags: bug

I was picked up yesterday because I appear to have double commented on some questions

[image]

[image]

This was not intentional and appears to be a result of my wifi disappearing momentarily due to local interference from other wifi hotspots.

Is this a bug, and what can I do to stop this happening again?

Comment: These are auto-comments, aren't they? Is that plugin not the most likely culprit?

Comment: @Oli I believe these are the comments inserted for you when you "Recommend Deletion" in the LQP review. I've had this happen to me once, I think it was because I was clicking around the options too much, though I can't reproduce it now.

Comment: @Oli the comment I sent to Bruno isn't in the auto-comments from the plug in but is in the comments from the review que.  I think I may have lost connection just as I was recommending deletion.  the server accepted it but since my connection was momentarily down I did not get a confirmation but an error message. I then resent it and the comment appeared twice.

Answer (score -1):

These look like auto-comments.  When you vote to delete something with /review and quote one of the preexising reasons for it, such as "Don't add Thank You" it can sometimes autopost one of these, and if you autocomment it yourself with the pro forma comments plugin, you'll end up with double comments.

Comment: I don't think you can comment in the LQP queue..

Comment: @Seth checked, you can add your own comments as well as the pre-existing ones.

Comment: I doubt he is manually commenting with the add comment button. As you can see, the comments are >1 min of difference.